# Question: $\;f(x)\to g(x) \Rightarrow f'(x)\to g'(x)\;$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $\;f:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow \mathbb R^m\;$ and $\;g:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R\;$ two functions such that:

1. $\;f(x_1+y_1,x_2) \to f(x_1,x_2)\;$ as $\;y_1 \to +\infty\;$ in $\;C^3_{loc}(\mathbb R^2;\mathbb R^m)\;$
2. $\;f(x_1,x_2) \to g(x_2)\;$ as $\;x_1 \to +\infty\;$

**QUESTION:**

Is it true that $\;\frac{\partial f(x_1+y_1,x_2)}{\partial x_1} \to \frac{\partial g(x_2)}{\partial x_1} = 0\;$ as $\;y_1\to +\infty\;?$

**My thoughts:**

Since $\;(1)\;$ holds, then $\;\frac{\partial f(x_1+y_1,x_2)}{\partial x_1} \to \frac{\partial f(x_1,x_2)}{\partial x_1}\;$

In addition, $\;f(x_1+y_1,x_2) \to f(x_1,x_2) \to g(x_2)\;$ as $\;y_1,x_1 \to +\infty\;$

Could I claim from the above that $\;f_{x_1}(x_1+y_1,x_2) \to g_{x_1}(x_2)=0\;?$

I've been stuck to this! Any help would be appreciated...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly goes to infinity in the question is it $y_1$ or $x_1$ or both? I don't understand...

Comment: @yanko My mistake! I'll edit

Comment: Doesn't (1) imply that, for all $x_1,x'_1,x_2$, we have $f(x_1,x_2) = \lim_{y\to\infty} f(x_1+y,x_2) = \lim_{y\to\infty} f(x'_1+y,x_2) = f(x'_1,x_2)$? It seems to me that for all $x_1,x'_1,x_2$, we have $f(x_1,x_2)=f(x'_1,x_2)$. So $f(x_1,x_2)=g(x_2)$. Did I understand the setup correctly?

Comment: @ZachTeitler Oh... so what you're saying is that the limit is independent of the choice of $\;x_1\;$ and this is why the limit function depends only on $\;x_2\;$. In this case, the problem solved! I guess the notation confused me a little. Thank you